# Why is this for loop not called if there are any preceding statements? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

Reading a csv, I find I'm unable to iterate through rows if there are any preceding statements in my `with` block.

For example, if I do this:

```
with open (TargetFile) as source:
        Strings = csv.reader(source)
        for row in Strings:
            print Strings.line_num
```

I'll get the integers 1 - (# of rows) printed to console. (Useless, yes, but I'm just testing the `for` with something obvious.)

However, say I'm looking to grab a row at random. I'd want to first determine the # of rows and generate a random number within that range, then iterate through the rows in search of a matching line_num.

(Here, I've kept the useless `print Strings.line_num` to avoid introducing new mistakes to the mix.)

```
    with open (TargetFile) as source:
        Strings = csv.reader(source)       
        CSV_Length = sum(1 for row in Strings)
        print CSV_Length
        RandRow = random.randrange(1,CSV_Length)
        print RandRow
        for row in Strings:
            print Strings.line_num
            #replace ^ with actually useful code
```

Will print the number of rows in the csv file and a random integer in that range to the console - all as expected - but the (previously working) `for` loop won't be called. Without that loop, I can't get to the useful and interesting bit

What am I missing, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing that `Strings` is an iterator. Once you iterate it to get the length, it is exhausted. So the for loop now has nothing to operate on.

You could fix this by converting to a list straight away:

```
strings = list(csv.reader(source))
```

Having done this, you could now access `len(strings)` to get the length anyway.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know iterators behaved that way. Interesting!

Won't that remove my ability to test against the line_num? I don't believe lists have that attribute.

Comment: True, but then you can use enumerate which is more explicit anyway: `for line_num, row in enumerate(strings)`.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, the problem is that you are iterating over lines in the file.  The proper solution, however, is to rewind the file:

```
Source.seek(0, 0)
```

This will put you back at the beginning of the file.